# Missing File extension in list for Select Default Program

Tags: windows, file-extension

Can't open xls files.  Go to Set Default Program but the file extension isn't in the list and can't find a means of adding it.  This seemed to happen after an auto Win 7 update. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have Excel installed?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click an .XLS file and choose `Open With...`.

Select Microsoft Office Excel from the list of "Recommended Programs", or "Other Programs", or you may have to browse for it (if it's not in either list).

Ensure you have "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" check-marked before you hit "OK".

Comment: It's not in the list yet I've been using excel and recently ran into this problem.

Comment: If it isn't in the list then choose other and browse to the exe